# Apply transition for dynamically appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, 2d, transform

Good day or night to the whole stackoverflow community! (Especially for those who are reading this )

- The thing is I have a big container.
- Several divs of the fixed height are appended into it on user's click.
- Those divs have header blocks and description blocks in them.

In the end I need their description blocks to have transform: translateY(dynamicHeight), where dynamicHeight is their height value which is dependent on the header block height (header height is not universal for all items. Each item may have its own header height). (Overall div height is 200px and if header block is 53px height, description block should take the rest 147px)

```js
$(function () {
  var itemsNumber = 4; //Say, I've got this number of items from a database.

  $("#btn").on("click", function () {
    for (i=0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {
      $("#container").append($("<div class=\"item\" id=" + i + "><div class=\"moving\"><div class=\"header\">Hi! I'm header.</div><div class=\"description\">Howdy. I am the content.</div></div></div>"));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#btn {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
 }
 
 #container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 550px;
 }
 
 .item {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 200px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
 }
 
 .moving {
  transform: translateY(147px); /* Need to calculate this value using jQuery or vanilla JavaScript (itemHeight - headerHeight) but have no idea how to do it, because items are added dynamically.. */
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 .item:hover .moving {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
 
 .moving div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 53px; /* This value isn't going be the same for each item */
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 
 .description {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">Add tems</div>
<div id="container"></div> <!-- Items are added to this div -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate dynamic height like this `$("#container").height() - $(".header").height();` and use this function `$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item", function()` to bind hover evcent to dynamically created elements like this

```js
$(function() {
  var itemsNumber = 4; //Say, I've got this number of items from a database.

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {
      $("#container").append($("<div class=\"item\" id=" + i + "><div class=\"moving\"><div class=\"header\" >Hi! I'm header.</div><div class=\"description\" >Howdy. I am the content.</div></div></div>"));


    }
    var hei = $("#container").height() - $(".header").height();
    $(".moving").css("transform", "translateY(" + hei + "px)"); //translate using  dynamic height
    $(".description").css("height", hei-2+"px"); //set height of description dynamically
  });

  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".item", function() {
    $(this).find(".moving").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
    $(this).find(".moving").css("transition", " transform .4s ease-in-out");
  });

  $(document).on("mouseleave", ".item", function() {
    var hei = $("#container").height() - $(".header").height();
    $(this).find(".moving").css("transform", "translateY(" + hei + "px)");
    $(this).find(".moving").css("transition", " transform .4s ease-in-out");
  });



});
```

```css
#btn {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 550px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
}

.moving div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 53px;
  /* This value isn't going be the same for each item */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.description {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">Add tems</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<!-- Items are added to this div -->
```

P.S. Also set height of `description` dynamically like this `$(".description").css("height", hei-2+"px");` : `-2px` is of borders each `1px` on `item` and `container`

Comment: Sadly, it won't work since header is of unexpected height and I need it all to be seen in its initial state (before hover).

Comment: @AlexanderPrisazhny I have updated my answer. Please check it

Comment: thank you! You see, the thing is - I need them to have transform:translateY(neededValue) initially (not on hover or whatever direct user event). 
Then transform:translateY(0) is used on hover, but 0 value shoudn't be calculated in my case.

Comment: transform:translateY(neededValue) initially is getting calculated initially only by `var hei = $("#container").height() - $(".header").height();$(".moving").css("transform", "translateY(" + hei + "px)");` in `click` event. The other one is when user mouse leaves the div

Comment: @AlexanderPrisazhny If it helped please accept and upvote the answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Probably, you meant .item?

var hei = $(".item").height() - $(".header").height();
$(".moving").css("transform", "translateY(" + hei + "px)");

But how can I select .item or .header if they are appended on runtime? Headers will be different in height and I need this value to be calculated for each particular item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158440/discussion-between-sanchit-patiyal-and-alexander-prisazhny).

Comment: You are confusing the things first you try this code on the scenario which you want to run and if there is some issue then we can discuss further